# Difference in "polar" command in Matlab from 2013 version to 2015

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I wanted to remove the numbers from the polar plot so I used the following:

```
myline = polar(txxx, pxxx); get handle of the data line
set(0,'Showhiddenhandles','on') % to show hidden handles
extrastuff = setdiff(get(gca,'children'),myline);
delete(extrastuff)
```

and it works in 2013b version but does not work in 2015 version. Can anyone help me to do the same in 2015 version.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853280/change-axis-in-polar-plots-in-matlab-to-radians. You can do something similar to avoid plotting the numbers

Comment: Thank you. It might work, let me try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `polar` function creates those text objects with their `'HandleVisibility'` set to `'off'`, so you can't see them from outside the function.

You can use a modified version of `polar` as follows:

1. Open file `polar.m`.
2. Find all lines that include `text(`. Those are the lines that create the text objects.
3. Comment out those lines, as well as their continuations.
4. Save the file with a different name, for example `polar2.m`.